# How resolve error 'awscrt.mqtt' has no attribute 'OnConnectionFailuredata' with AWS Iot core sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot-core

I got : AWS_ERROR_MQTT_TIMEOUT: Time limit between request and response has been exceeded

So when i use sdk examples it work finely.

I try to connect my device to aws iot core via python sdk but it not work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in AWS IoT but it seems like two problems here:

`OnConnectionFailuredata` - looks like a bug in the sample. It must refer `OnConnectionFailureData`, not `OnConnectionFailuredata` (uppercase D). You can easily fix it yourself in the pubsub.py.

`AWS_ERROR_MQTT_TIMEOUT` - I'm not sure about this but I guess the Greengrass is unable to reach your device. As a suggestion consider `nmap -p 8443 $you_device_endpoint` to check if the port is open.